# Controlar uma nova aba com o Cypress

Tags: javascript, json, testes-automatizados, cypress

Estou testando uma aplicação com o Cypress, e estou com um problema.

[image: Gerenciar]
Ao clicar no button(Gerenciar) abre uma nova aba e gostaria de saber se tem como eu forçar a abrir na mesma ou fazer o cypress utilizar a nova aba.
Não é possível passar a url por causa do token.

```
it('Nova aba Produto', () => {
    cy.Login();
    cy.get(':nth-child(7) > a > .fa').click();
    cy.get('#drop-user > .fa').click();
    cy.get('.mt-auto').click();// Abre outra guia
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizar ".invoke('removeAttr', 'target')" que irá forçar a abrir na mesma aba.

```
cy.get('Elemento')
.invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
.click()
```

Answer (score -3):

O código HTML da pagina está abrindo uma nova aba, e o cypress não trabalha com multiplas abas, uma solução seria alterar o HTML da pagina para que ele não abra uma nova aba, mas talvez algo nesse link possa te ajudar a testar o que você precisa: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/integration/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.js